# java.lang.NullPointerException in Struts2 application

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts 2 . I am working on a web application when I am adding action mapping in struts.xml, i am getting following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

in struts.xml i have added following code

```
<action name="ChangePassword" class="com.my.action.Welcome">
            <result name="success" >/changepassword.jsp</result>       
        </action>
```

following is my welcome action

```
package com.mmi.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Welcome extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

i have created Welcome action in com.my.action package. Don't know what to do..

Comment: can you post the `Welcome` class

Comment: not clear yet. can you debug the code and narrow the code where the error reside?

Comment: can you replace result name as forward name and check. Also verify if changepassword is directly under WEBContent.Let me know if it works